# Error: no matching function for call to swap

Tags: c++

This is only a part of my code, for quick sort. 
It keeps returning the error: "no matching function for call to swap"

Why and how do I fix it?

```
using namespace std;    
void print_array(int array[], int low, int hi)    
{
    cout<< "quick sort partition steps: ";    
    for (int j=low; j<=hi;j++)
        cout <<" "<< array[j];
    cout << endl;    
}
//end of print_array

int partition (int arr[], int low, int hi)    
{    
    int pivot = arr[hi];
    int i = low;

    for (int j = low; j<hi; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            swap(arr, i, j);
            i++;
        }
    }
    print_array(arr, low, hi);
    swap(arr, i, hi);       
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Looking at some documentation for `std::swap` is a good start. It doesn't even have three parameters.

Comment: Did you define your own swap function? If so, did you declare it above the first usage? As currently written, this question cannot be answered

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use `std::swap`, try this:

- `swap(arr[i], arr[j]);` instead of `swap(arr, i, j);`
- `swap(arr[i], arr[hi]);` instead of `swap(arr, i, hi);`